# Decide CUDA threads and blocks for image processing

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda

**Dear DOWNVOTERS:** kindly let me know the reason of down vote. I have already accepted an answer which means that the person was able to understand the problem and a minimal working example was not required. Secondly, I wanted it to be a **conceptual question** rather than a homework problem. Please let me know the reason of your down-vote.

**IMPORTANT:** I have already read several thread (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392250/understanding-cuda-grid-dimensions-block-dimensions-and-threads-organization-s)) about the distribution of threads and blocks but I have a specific query.

I have to process an image data in `unsigned char` form at GPU. My image is of size `(1080 x 1920)` with 3 channels and each pixel is of `unsigned char` type.

**GPU [Details](http://www.nvidia.de/content/PDF/data-sheet/DS_NV_Quadro_K2000_OCT13_NV_US_LR.pdf):**

```
NVIDIA Quadro k2000
2 GB of GDDR5 GPU memory
384 5MX CUDA parallel processing cores
```

As, I am new to GPU processing, I am not able to understand much about the number of threads per block and total number of block distribution for my GPU card in this specific case.

**PROBLEM:** When I use the following 
configuration for my `(1080 x 1920)` image to call the GPU kernel then, I am getting the desired results but the computational time is too much

```
dim3 numOfBlocks( (108) , (192) ); 
dim3 numOfThreadsPerBlocks( 3*10 , 3*10 ); //multiplied by 3 because we have 3 channel image now

colorTransformation_kernel<<<numOfBlocks, numOfThreadsPerBlocks>>>(numChannels, step_size, iw, ih, dev_ptr_source, dev_ptr_dst);
```

**but**, if I choose to have the following another configuration

```
    dim3 numOfBlocks( (108/2) , (192/2) ); 
    dim3 numOfThreadsPerBlocks( 3*10*2 , 3*10*2 ); //multiplied by 3 because we have 3 channel image now
```

then, I get a blank image.

Comment: do you do [error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api/14038590#14038590)? please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @m.s. : there is no error. Please tell me, what could be the minimal working example?? Isn't it a logical question?? I have provided all the details about my image, GPU, numBlocks, what else is required. Kindly let me know what other information is required, I will post it.

Comment: how do you know there is no error? If you get a blank image, your kernel might not have been run, which is something you could detect by checking  CUDA API errors. A MCVE typically consists of code which can be copied, pasted and compiled without any necessary changes to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @m.s.: I wanted to keep it as a logical question rather than a homework type problem. Moreover, I am taking images from electron-microscopy camera then, you will need my image too. Hardware is also different. I can't post all the things at SO.

Comment: @skm... [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17124599/1231073) may be of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you applied [error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api/14038590#14038590) as I already suggested in the comments, the output would be:

> [invalid configuration argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125389/invalid-configuration-argument-error-for-the-call-of-cuda-kernel)

You are using a Quadro K2000, which [has Compute
capability 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Supported_GPUs). Compute capability 3.0 allows to have a maximum of [1024 threads per block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications).

You are using `3*10*2 * 3*10*2 = 3600` threads per block, which is above the 1024 limit. 
So your kernel didn't even run, which is why you are getting a blank image.

Comment: thanks a lot. `error checking` has helped a lot. I found that kernel did not even load as you mentioned. I was confused about the number of threads allowed at my GPU and I could not get the information about it.

Comment: Could you suggest me, what could be the possible optimized configuration for that. Or, I just need to make a configuration which can minimize the number of blocks and maximize the maximum number of threads per block ?

Comment: @skm have a look at the various SO question dealing with this issue, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592450/how-to-adjust-the-cuda-number-of-block-and-of-thread-to-get-optimal-performances, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985912/how-do-i-choose-grid-and-block-dimensions-for-cuda-kernels